# How do I allow certain roles to run a command?

Tags: javascript

So I want to create my own discord bot, and I want to only allow admins to run certain commands.

The only thing I've done to the bot is adding some anti-advertising system and a -help command.

I only want admins to run that certain command.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like https://www.devdungeon.com/content/javascript-discord-bot-tutorial using the discord.js NPM to get you started.

To only allow admins to send commands the simple solution would be to check if the person sending the message is one of your admins before executing any more code

```
if (receivedMessage.author == "adminusername"){
   //do stuff
}
```